# Writing better SQL code by avoiding redundancy

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a sql query like this :

```
SELECT Code 
FROM xyz 
WHERE xyz.Code  IN  ('20','10') AND price = 
    (select min(price) FROM xyz  WHERE CODE IN  ('20','10'));
```

Desired Output After Query : 10

Table xyz :-

Price : 1  2  1

Code  : 10 20 30

Is there any better way to write this sql statement? Because in my sql statement "WHERE CODE IN  ('20','10')" gets repeated twice, and i am trying to avoid calling this statement twice

Answer (score 6):

If you want to receive only one row you can use ORDER BY and LIMIT:

```
SELECT Code
FROM xyz
WHERE xyz.Code IN ('20','10')
ORDER BY price
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `join` to filter, instead of a `where in` condition.  That would allow you to have the joined table re-use the condition from the first table.

```
select  Code 
from    (
        select  *
        from    xyz
        where   code in ('20','10')
        ) t1 
inner join
        (
        select  code
        ,       min(price) as min_price
        from    xyz
        group by
                code
        ) filter
on      filter.code = t1.code
        and filter.min_price = t1.price
```

Comment: I think this will give two rows output, not one.